# Centrality measures in graphs (closeness, degree, betweeness)

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible for a graph to have `Closeness`, `Betweenness` and `Degree` centrality on 3 different nodes?

I have think about two complete graphs of `n` nodes that are connected by a single node. But this graph has two of three on the central node.If it's not possible, why?

Comment: I'm not sure what picture I should draw.  Is the single node *shared* by both complete graphs $K_n$, or is it a node not belonging to either clique but joined to both cliques, e.g. by a single edge?  It might help to say which two kinds of centrality you believe such a node possesses (and why *not* the third kind).